# How to do a runtime cast

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

I'm on a web application that I write in TypeScript. In one part of the application, the use can write an additional JavaScript function, that will be parsed at runtime (`new function(Function as String)`) for execution. The code will give me back an object which I defined in TypeScript as `class Script`. This script object should contain specific functions, otherwise it's invalid. Meaning, I want  to throw an exception, if one or more functions are not implemented by the user.

A Typescript cast won't do it, as it is a compile time cast.

I thought about giving the `Script` object a constructor that takes the parsed object (that, by key/values, should be a `Script`object already) and check the object in the constructor for missing properties. 
Something like this:
(This will not work, it only should show the idea)

```
export class Script {
    constructor(object: Script) {
    this.getDefaultValue = object.getDefaultValue;
    this.isAvailable = object.isAvailable;
    this.isValid = object.isValid;
    this.isInRange = object.isInRange;
    this.isDataFormat = object.isDataFormat;

    for (let propertie in this){
        if (!this[propertie]){
        throw new Error(propertie+ ' is missing.');
        }
    }
    }
    getDefaultValue: any;
    isAvailable: (containerSetId: number) => boolean;
    isValid: (value: any) => boolean;
    isInRange: (value: any) => any;
    isDataFormat: (value: any) => boolean;
}
```

But isn't there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: No this code, does not work. I added a note. It's kind of a pseudo code

Comment: And you want to check with that loop, if all the above properties are set or undefined?

Comment: Yes, and if one is undefined, throw an exception because the given object, apparently is not of the type `Script`

Comment: You are spot on. IMO the best you can do is a series of `typeof` and `instanceof` checks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use that because:

```
class A {
    member1: string;
    member2: number;
    member3: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.member3 = true;
    }
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.member3 = true;
    }
    return A;
}());
```

As you can see, the `member1` and `member2` are not part of the compiled js version.
You'll need to keep track of the required properties for runtime, something like:

```
class Script {
    getDefaultValue: any;
    isAvailable: (containerSetId: number) => boolean;
    isValid: (value: any) => boolean;
    isInRange: (value: any) => any;
    isDataFormat: (value: any) => boolean;

    required = [
        "getDefaultValue",
        "isAvailable",
        "isValid",
        "isInRange",
        "isDataFormat"
    ]

    constructor(object: Script) {
        this.getDefaultValue = object.getDefaultValue;
        this.isAvailable = object.isAvailable;
        this.isValid = object.isValid;
        this.isInRange = object.isInRange;
        this.isDataFormat = object.isDataFormat;

        for (let propertie in this.required) {
            if (!this[propertie] || typeof this[propertie] !== "function") {
                throw new Error(propertie+ ' is missing.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reasoning. That works perfectly.

this one `!typeof this[propertie] === "function"` needs aditional brackets => `!(typeof this[propertie] === "function")`

Comment: My bad. I changed it to `typeof this[propertie] !== "function"`

Comment: well yeah, that's actually better :D